# What package of SignalR use for production

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have developed the application with Asp.Net MVC 5 and I want to use the SignalR.

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR - Package `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR`

Is it possible use this library for `production` enviroment?

I've found another package: https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR but it's probable package still in development.

Thanks for the clarification

Comment: Why not just use NuGet to get the latest version installed in your Visual Studio project? See here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR

Comment: I don't specify the question very well. I mean which library is possible use for production use.

Comment: I believe version 2.2.1 is the latest stable version

Comment: This is stable version for Asp.Net and for Asp.Net Core probable is not stable, is'nt it?

Comment: Ah. I don't know about .NET Core if it is in beta or stable

Comment: For ASP.NET core it is not production ready yet. See https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/429#issuecomment-298179283